# What is the implementation detail for enumerate?

Tags: python, loops, allocation, enumerate

Python has `enumerate()` to iterate over objects with an index.I doubt that interpreters create a lot of int objects for the sole purpose of keeping track of where things are. The [PEP page](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/)  says the following, but I do not really understand what is going on under the hood:

> It provides all iterables with the same advantage that iteritems() affords to dictionaries -- a compact, readable, reliable index notation.

So what is the magic here?

Comment: Python creates a lot of `int` objects *everywhere*, but interns the small values (somewhere in the range -5 through to 256).

Comment: @jamylak I am new to Ptyhon so I have trouble finding the source code just by googling. Which one of those files contain the source code for `enumerate`?

Comment: @Forethinker: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/enumobject.c

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`enumerate()` is an iterator; it only produces the index `int` value *on the fly*; it does not produce them all up front.

You can try to read the [`enumobject.c` source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/enumobject.c), but it basically can be translated to Python like this:

```
def enumerate(iterable, start=0):
    count = start
    for elem in iterable:
        yield count, elem
        count += 1
```

The `yield` keyword makes this a [generator function](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions), and you need to loop over the generator (or call `next()` on it) to advance the function to produce data, one `yield` call at a time.

Python also interns `int` values, all values between -5 and 256 (inclusive) are singletons, so the above code doesn't even produce new `int` objects until you reach 257.

Comment: Programming language source code is still a bit daunting for me. Anyone who brushes up on `yield` will get this right away. Thanks a lot Martijn!

Answer (score 2):

It helps you know where things are....

```
l = ['apple', 'banana', 'cabbage']

for idx, item in enumerate(l):
    print "the item: %s, is at position %s" % (item, idx)

>>> 
the item: apple, is at position 0
the item: banana, is at position 1
the item: cabbage, is at position 2
```

This helps in the following scenario.. Imagine you want to find every 'cabbage' item in the list. And know their indexes.

```
l = ['apple', 'banana', 'cabbage', 'monkey', 'kangaroo', 'cabbage']

def find_indexes(lst, match):
    results = []
    for idx, item in enumerate(l):
        if item == match:
            results.append(idx)
    return results

print find_indexes(l, 'cabbage')

>>> 
[2, 5]
```